# Instead of quantizing gravity, why not try to "gravitize" quantum theory, or clarify it and perhaps render it more deterministic

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, gravity, quantum-interpretations

Many physicists seem to be trying to formulate a theory of quantum gravity. But there is a different or opposite approach highlighted by some insightful remarks by Roger Penrose.

In a 2013 paper entitled "On the Gravitization of Quantum Mechanics 1: Quantum State Reduction", Penrose wrote:

> This paper argues that the case for “gravitizing” quantum theory is at least as strong as that for quantizing gravity.Accordingly, the principles of general relativity must influence, and actually change, the very formalism of quantum mechanics. Most particularly, an“Einsteinian”,rather than a“Newtonian” treatment of the gravitational field should be adopted, in a quantum system,in order that the principle of equivalence be fully respected. This leads to an expectation that quantum superpositions of states involving a significant mass displacement should have a finite lifetime[...]

> The title of this article contains the phrase “gravitization of quantum Mechanics” in contrast to the more usual “quantization of gravity”. This reversal of wording is deliberate, of course, indicating my concern with the bringing of quantum theory more in line with the principles of Einstein’s general relativity, rather than attempting to make Einstein’s theory—or any more amenable theory of gravity—into line with those of quantum mechanics (or quantum field theory).[...]

> I think that people tend to regard the great twentieth century revolution of quantum theory, as a more fundamental scheme of things than gravitational theory. Indeed, quantum mechanics, strange as its basic principles seem to be, has no evidence against it from accepted experiment orobservation, and people tend to argue that this theory is so well established now that one must try to bring the whole of physics within its compass.Yet, that other great twentieth century revolution, namely the general theory of relativity,is also a fundamental scheme of things which, strange as its basic principles seem to be, also has no confirmed experiments or observations that tell against it[...]

In his book *The Road to Reality*, Penrose stated:

> [...]there are powerful positive reasons [...] to believe that the laws of present-day quantum mechanics are in need of a fundamental (though presumably subtle) change. These reasons come from within accepted physical principles and from observed facts about the universe. Yet, I find it remarkable how few of today’s quantum physicists are prepared to entertain seriously the idea of an actual change in the ground rules of their subject. Quantum mechanics, despite its extraordinary exception-free experimental support and strikingly confirmed predictions, is a comparatively young subject, being only about three-quarters of a century old (dating this from the establishment of the mathematical theory by Dirac and others, based on the schemes of Heisenberg and Schrodinger, in the years immediately following 1925).

> [After Newton's gravitational theory] Einstein’s theory [...] involved a completely radical change in perspective. This, it seems to me, is the general kind of change in the structure of quantum mechanics that we must look towards, if we are to obtain the (in my view) needed non-linear theory to replace the present-day conventional quantum theory. Indeed, it is my own perspective that Einstein’s general relativity will itself supply some necessary clues as to the modifications that are required. The 20th century gave us two fundamental revolutions in physical thought— and, to my way of thinking, general relativity has provided as impressive a revolution as has quantum theory (or quantum Field theory). Yet, these two great schemes for the world are based upon principles that lie most uncomfortably with each other. The usual perspective, with regard to the proposed marriage between these theories, is that one of them, namely general relativity, must submit itself to the will of the other. There appears to be the common view that the rules of quantum Field theory are immutable, and it is Einstein’s theory that must bend itself appropriately to fit into the standard quantum mould. Few would suggest that the quantum rules must themselves admit to modification, in order to ensure an appropriately harmonious marriage. Indeed, the very name ‘quantum gravity’, that is normally assigned to the proposed union, carries the implicit connotation that it is a standard quantum (field) theory that is sought. Yet, I would claim that there is observational evidence that Nature’s view of this union is very different from this! I contend that her design for this union must be what, in our eyes, would be a distinctly non-standard one, and that an objective state reduction must be one of its important features.

Penrose also criticized the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics, and presented a more favorable opinion of the de Broglie-Bohm interpretation.

In light of Penrose's ideas and views, what are your thoughts on the possibility of quantizing gravity, and about the alternatives or opposite approaches?

Are theories such as loop quantum gravity or twistor theory viable, accurate or useful approaches?

Comment: Your question is mostly about opinion, and will soon be closed. One would note, however, if someone as good at mathematics as Penrose is himself unable to gravitise quantum theory, then it is scarcely sensible to get mere mortals to achieve what he has not been able to. The problem of quantum gravity is _really difficult._

Comment: Respectfully, this is not the place to ask people their speculative opinions regarding potential future theories of physics. Questions should have objective answers based on our current understanding of physics.

Comment: I made a few changes to the question. I think this is an important question about the future direction of research on gravity and physics in general, and related topics. I was hoping to bring about some fruitful and productive discussions and ideas about the recent theories and the latest trends in research in physics.

Comment: The future direction of quantum gravity research is the same as the past direction: it's the search for an experiment or observation that can demonstrate that gravity is a quantum phenomenon, after all. So far we have not found any way to get beyond classical gravity. That theoretical physicists have lots of ideas about it is pretty much irrelevant. Theoretical physicists had a lot of ideas about the structure of matter before quantum mechanics was discovered... and all of them were false.